# Python, mostrar índice de uma linha específica dentro da matriz

Tags: python, matriz

Caros Senhores(as),

Poderiam me dar uma ajuda.. uma ideia?!

--> Estou tentando apresentar(imprimir) o índice(a linha) do maior intervalo entre o maior e o menor termo das linhas de uma matriz se encontram.

Por exemplo: Imaginem uma matriz com 3 linhas e 2 colunas.
[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 11],[12, 13, 20]]

Portanto, o maior intervalo seria da linha 3, pois 20-12=8.

Eu gostaria de que a saída fosse: Linha 3, com maior intervalo valendo 8

O código abaixo apresenta a sequência de linhas e o valor do intervalo.

Eu já havia conseguido mostrar o index de cada linha, mas eu gostaria apenas da que tiver o maior valor de intervalo.

Por gentileza, o problema está no ultimo "for" do código. Lá em baixo.

```
   import random

    matriz = [] #cria matriz vazia
    m = int(input("Informe a qtd de linhas desejadas na Matriz: "))
    n = int(input("Informe a qtd de colunas desejadas na Matriz: "))
    a = int(input("Defina o início do intervalo para geração aleatória: "))
    b = int(input("Defina o fim do intervalo para geração aleatória: "))
    maior = None  # Armazena o maior valor
    posicao = (0, 0)  # Armazena a posição do maior valor

    for i in range(1, m+1):
        linha = []
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            x = float(random.uniform(a, b)) #gera números aleatórios dentro do intervalo definido
            if maior is None or x > maior:
                maior = x
                posicao = (i, j)

            linha.append(x)
        matriz.append(linha)

    produto = 1 #armazenará o produto dos maiores
    soma = 0 #armazenará a soma dos menores
    for linha in matriz:
        produto *= max(linha) #produto do maior valor de cada linha
        soma += min(linha) #soma do menor valor de cada linha

    for index, i in enumerate(matriz):
        maior_da_linha = max(i)
        menor_da_linha = min(i)
        intervalo = maior_da_linha - menor_da_linha
        index += 1
        print(index, i, intervalo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
matriz = [[5, 6, 347], [8, 9, 311], [12, 13, 20]]

def getIndexOfLongerRange (mat):
  ranges = [max(l) - min(l) for l in mat] # Criar lista de intervalos
  return ranges.index(max(ranges)) # Retorna o índice do maior intervalo

print (getIndexOfLongerRange(matriz))
```

Comment: @WilsonJunior, aqui o link com o seu código e o meu https://repl.it/repls/MiserlyHardShell

Comment: Mantenho meu agradecimento a você!